# Performant way to build long strings in a loop?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a loop that builds up a pretty large string. With every iteration a little string snippet is added to that string, and that string becomes bigger and bigger. Is there something better than using an NSMutableString and appending another string to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with appending to a string is that unless the string has preallocated all the space required, you're going to need to do some allocations and copying, leading to O(n^2) performance.

A more performant way is to build an NSArray of your list of strings using [NSArray:componentsJoinedByString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:).  Appending to the array is constant time, and since it knows the length of the resulting string before hand, it can provide you the final string in O(n) time.